# Remotely start LXDE via SSH

Tags: ssh, lxde, x-server

How can I remotely (e.g. via ssh) start lxde on my linux box which has no keyboard and mouse but only a monitor attached to it?

I can login via ssh fine.

Comment: no. You can't start whole DE over SSH. It was never designed for such tasks. You can connect directly over X protocol if it is local network or over VNC.

Comment: Well, you can start X and after that, connect using X over SSH...

Comment: @Jakuje are your sure that its not possible? Shouldnt it be possible somehow with setting the DISPLAY variable to output everything to the graphicscard instead over ssh?