# How to start x11vnc by socket (ie only when needed)

Tags: arch-linux, x11, systemd, vnc

Actually I start x11vnc in `/home/odroid/.config/lxsession/LXDE/autostart` with

```
@/bin/x11vnc -bg -forever -shared -rfbauth /home/odroid/.vnc-passwd -noxdamage -norc -noxrecord -capslock -no6 -rfbport 5900
```

Autologin on startup is ok and it works well.
But I log rarely in graphics mode.

I want it to work like sshd.socket (vs sshd.service)
Do you have an idea or line of research?

Comment: [Like this?](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/TigerVNC#Multi-user_mode)

Comment: If you rarely use it, why not just do X11 forwarding though?

Comment: @Bratchley thank you for you interest in my problem. I followed your link and that's a good track. But I am worried that I try to clarify this. - I dont understand "X11 forwarding though" sorry, limited skills

Comment: If your desktop runs an X server on it (such as FreeBSD, OS X, Linux, etc) most ssh clients can forward the displays for X11 programs from remote servers to your local desktop. The application runs on the server, but it sends instructions to the x server on your local machine instructing it how to update the window. In the case of windows, you have to download and install an X server component. Xming is a popular choice for that and it's low enough on resources to just leave running.

Comment: Good idea but I am having some problems. I continue with Answer 2 for ease of reading.

Answer (score 1):

So I create `/etc/systemd/system/xvnc.socket`

```
[Unit]
Description=XVNC Server

[Socket]
ListenStream=5900
Accept=yes

[Install]
WantedBy=sockets.target
```

And `/etc/systemd/system/xvnc@.service`

```
[Unit]
Description=XVNC Per-Connection Daemon

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/bin/x11vnc -display :0 -bg -forever -shared -rfbauth /home/odroid/.vnc-passwd -noxdamage -norc -noxrecord -capslock -inetd
User=odroid
StandardInput=socket
StandardError=syslog
```

After reboot I can connect from my PC :)

Answer (score 0):

First
jeep is the serveur (ARM Archlinux without physical screen).
My PC is under Archlinux.

I try @Bratchley suggestion.
I change `X11Forwarding` to `yes` in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` and restart `sshd.socket`
Works fine :)
I can connect from PC with `ssh -Y root@jeep`
If I launch `lxterminal` I have a terminal window on jeep :)

But I need entire LXDE desktop of jeep. Not just "applications deporting".
Because I use conky for monitoring many informations.
So I disable `lightdm.service` and reboot jeep

And....
If I launch `startlxde` or `lxsession` (on jeep of course) I have a graphical logon screen of ..... my PC !!!

After many search I found this [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/255948/remotely-start-lxde-via-ssh) and if I understand correctly is not possible :(

So I return to my first question (launch x11vnc by socket)